# Can 2 nodes exchange data concurrently with only 1 tcp connection?

Tags: networking, tcp

Say there are 2 nodes - A and B. Each of them maintains a state, which is a number in their memory. If A sends an `increment` somehow to B, then B will return `1`. A sends an `increment` again, B will return `2`. And so on. Same for B. And both A and B can update its state atomically.

For sending the `increment`, let's say B starts a TCP server to accept connections, and A is the client that establishes the connection with B. A can send `increment` to B through that established TCP connection.

Now, the question is: Can B also send `increment` to A through the same connection, and can A respond back with its own state through that connection?

Moreover, can A and B both send `increment`s and respond to each other concurrently through the same connection? So that if A and B send `increment` simultaneously to each other, they can respond back with `1`.

It’s an easy problem if A and B establish 2 connections - one for A as the client to send `increment` to B, and the other for A as the server to respond `increment` from B. And since there are 2 connections, A and B can send “increment” concurrently. But I wonder if it’s possible for A and B to exchange data with only one TCP connection? Does any protocol support this?

Comment: TCP creates a connection between two peers, and either can send and receive data, even at the same time, across the connection, and either can terminate the connection at any time. TCP does not have the concept of server or client, only peers. The client/server concept is an application concept. You will find nothing about clients or servers in the TCP RFC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. A and B can both exchange data through the same connection. However, one of them will act as a server and the other as a client. In fact, even if A tries to connect to B and B to A **at the same exact time**, TCP is designed so that scenario results in **only** one connection. This situation is called *simultaneous opening*. Keep in mind that the classic concept of *client* and *server* don't exist per se in the TCP specs (they're just *peers*), although is intuitive and helpful to regard the peer that performs the *active opening* as a client and the one that perform the *passive opening* as a server.

As per data exchange, both can send `increment` messages to each other through the same connection. Check [RFC 675](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc675) and [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)(The TCP reference) for more detailed in depth info.

Comment: Actually, The RFC for TCP is _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes yes it is. Got the numbers wrong in a typo. Changed it a bit ago already.